# Flutter-Quill editor not working inside a scrollable form

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I would like to put my `QuillEditor` inside my form and not on a dedicated page of my app.

I've tried with a `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` and with a `ListView` widget, but the result is the same:

- since there is no text, the editor is small and I would like it to be "expanded" (I know it can't be as such inside a scroll, but you get the point);
- the overflow of the text does not make the page scroll accordingly, so the users can't see what they are typing.

Here's some code:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Reply form"),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        tooltip: "Send",
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Form(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text("From: test@my.org"),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          chipInputField(
            label: "To",
            onChanged: (List<Object?> o) {},
            initialValue: ["first@email.it"],
          ),
          chipInputField(
            label: "Cc",
            onChanged: (List<Object?> o) {},
            initialValue: ["second@email.it"],
          ),
          chipInputField(
            label: "Bcc",
            onChanged: (List<Object?> o) {},
            initialValue: ["third@email.it"],
          ),
          QuillEditor(
            controller: quillController,
            scrollable: true,
            scrollController: ScrollController(),
            focusNode: FocusNode(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            autoFocus: true,
            readOnly: false,
            expands: false,
            placeholder: "compose_email",
          ),
          QuillToolbar.basic(
            controller: quillController,
            showUnderLineButton: false,
            showStrikeThrough: false,
            showColorButton: false,
            showBackgroundColorButton: false,
            showListCheck: false,
            showIndent: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

First issue: the compose email part is not expanded inside the application page

[image: the compose email part is not expanded inside the application page]

Second issue: as long as I write some text, the widget is not scrolling

[image: the keyboard is over the text and the widget is not scrolling]

Edit: I'm using Flutter 2.2.3 and flutter_quill: 1.3.3

Comment: Please specify the Flutter and Quill version in which you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: @niccord Are you still looking for answer?

Comment: Yes, I am. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after many tries to solve this answer I've realized the following and came up with a solution that might help you.

a `textField` in a listview that has `maxlines: null` will auto-scroll the listView with no issues but for some reason, flutter_quill has some issues

now my work around this is as follows ( **full code will be at the bottom** ):

1. first we define a couple of variables in the state class of the widget that has this form

```
final quill.QuillController quillController = quill.QuillController.basic();
final FocusNode editorFocusNode = FocusNode();
bool isToolBarVisible = true;
```

you already have the controller defined but for the other 2 attributes, you will need them to show/hide the toolbar based on the focused node.

2. instead of using a simple ListView, we use a customScrollView which makes it possible for us to create a more complex listview, it uses slivers ( a sliver is a scrollable widget, you can learn more [about it](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers) )

```
Form(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                toolbarHeight: isToolBarVisible ? 50 : 0,
                title:
                    Visibility(visible: isToolBarVisible, child: getToolBar()),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Column(
                  children: getTextFields(),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                hasScrollBody: true,
                child: getEditor(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

using the sliver app bar we can pin the quill toolbar, using the sliver to box adapter we can add the normal text fields, and then to expand the quill editor we use sliverFillRemaining.

here are the sub-functions:

```
 Widget getToolBar() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: quill.QuillToolbar.basic(
        controller: quillController,
        showUnderLineButton: false,
        showStrikeThrough: false,
        showColorButton: false,
        showBackgroundColorButton: false,
        showListCheck: false,
        showIndent: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getTextFields() {
    return [
      Text("From: test@my.org"),
      SizedBox(height: 8),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "To"),
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Cc"),
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Bcc"),
      ),
    ];
  }

  Widget getEditor() {
    return QuillEditor(
      controller: quillController,
      scrollable: true,
      scrollController: ScrollController(),
      focusNode: editorFocusNode,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      autoFocus: true,
      readOnly: false,
      expands: false,
      placeholder: "compose_email",
    );
  }
```

**replace the normal textFields with your chipInputField**

finally here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' as quill;
import 'package:flutter_quill/widgets/editor.dart';

class FlutterQuillForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlutterQuillFormState createState() => _FlutterQuillFormState();
}

class _FlutterQuillFormState extends State<FlutterQuillForm> {
  final quill.QuillController quillController = quill.QuillController.basic();
  final FocusNode editorFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool isToolBarVisible = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    editorFocusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isToolBarVisible = editorFocusNode.hasFocus;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reply form"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.send),
            tooltip: "Send",
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                toolbarHeight: isToolBarVisible ? 50 : 0,
                title:
                    Visibility(visible: isToolBarVisible, child: getToolBar()),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Column(
                  children: getTextFields(),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                hasScrollBody: true,
                child: getEditor(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getToolBar() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: quill.QuillToolbar.basic(
        controller: quillController,
        showUnderLineButton: false,
        showStrikeThrough: false,
        showColorButton: false,
        showBackgroundColorButton: false,
        showListCheck: false,
        showIndent: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getTextFields() {
    return [
      Text("From: test@my.org"),
      SizedBox(height: 8),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "To"),
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Cc"),
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Bcc"),
      ),
    ];
  }

  Widget getEditor() {
    return QuillEditor(
      controller: quillController,
      scrollable: true,
      scrollController: ScrollController(),
      focusNode: editorFocusNode,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      autoFocus: true,
      readOnly: false,
      expands: false,
      placeholder: "compose_email",
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    quillController.dispose();
  }
}
```

in the focus node listener, we can set the state of the toolbar to be visible or invisible and don't forget to dispose the controllers and the focus node.

screenshots:

[image: toolbar hidden]
[image: toolbar showing]
[image: auto-scroll]

Comment: I have a lot of error messages in the console while trying it out. This is not fully working. Probably because of those errors it doesn't show the toolbar. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: I have updated the flutter_quill version to 1.6.4 and it seems to work! Thank you!!

Comment: Im glad i was able to help!

Comment: Do you scroll the whole page (include to / cc / bcc) when you scroll the quillEditor? Or is the rest of the page fixed in its original position?
If so, what is the difference between using Column and ScrollView?

Comment: I have a similar problem, if I nest the whole page in scroll view, then my quillEditor can't scroll automatically with the cursor. If I use Column, then quillEditor works perfectly fine, but it can't drive the rest of the page to scroll together (because Column can't scroll)

What I want is to make sure that the quillEditor can scroll with the cursor and drag the quillEditor to scroll the whole page. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hello my people I was struggling on how I ca implement rich text editor and I found Quill html editor,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWQT3.png)

This code can do this things

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).