# Flutter QuillEditor not following cursor inside a ListView

Tags: flutter, quill, scrollable

I have a page made like this

```dart
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  20,
                  10,
                  20,
                  10,
                ),
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        handleTouch();
                        changeStateToEdited();
                      },
                      enabled: owner,
                      minLines: 1,
                      maxLines: null,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        height: 1,
                        fontSize: 35,
                        color:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, bottom: 10),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Titolo",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 35
                          color: Theme.of(context)
                              .colorScheme
                              .onSecondaryContainer
                              .withAlpha(100),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                      controller: titleController,
                    ),
                    Original.Text(
                      "text",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context)
                            .colorScheme
                            .secondary
                            .withAlpha(80),
                      ),
                    ),
                    QuillEditor(
                      controller: contentController,
                      readOnly: !owner!,
                      autoFocus: false,
                      placeholder: "Contenuto",
                      customStyles: DefaultStyles(
                        placeHolder: DefaultListBlockStyle(
                          TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                .colorScheme
                                .onSurfaceVariant
                                .withAlpha(100),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                          Tuple2(0, 0),
                          Tuple2(0, 0),
                          BoxDecoration(),
                          null,
                        ),
                      ),
                      expands: false,
                      focusNode: contentFocusNode,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      scrollController: contentScrollController,
                      scrollable: true,
                      // minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 400,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            QuillToolbar.basic(
              controller: contentController,
              multiRowsDisplay: false,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

When editing and writing some text, the "focus" won't follow the cursor.
It's not autoscrolling to the cursor, like a normal TextField would do.

The main issue is that the property `expands` is set to false.
So I tried, and set it to true, but doing this it gives me unbounded height error.
To fix it, I tried to wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets but still, gives me the same error. I then tried just to test it, to wrap it with a container of fixed height e.g. 100 and I noticed that that's not what I'm looking for, since, even if it works, it only scrolls that container, and not the whole page when editing;

I can provide more code if you need it.
Probably stupid question, sorry about it, but Quill package has 0 docs and I couldn't find anything similar, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351418/flutter-quill-editor-not-working-inside-a-scrollable-form) which is **not** what I'm looking for.

Thank you